# Manually calculating IRR formula

Tags: economics

I am new to economics maths and I have to solve some issues.

I am trying to solve the following equation : 
$$-156000 + \frac{57080}{(1+irr)^1} + \frac{81080}{(1+irr)^2} + \frac{176480}{(1+irr)^3} + \frac{213680}{(1+irr)^4} + \frac{190280}{(1+irr)^5} = 0$$

I solved the equation in Excel and the result is $0.8976$.

Could you help me please do it manually?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-156000+%2B+%5Cfrac%7B57080%7D%7B(1%2Bx)%5E1%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7B81080%7D%7B(1%2Bx)%5E2%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7B176480%7D%7B(1%2Bx)%5E3%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7B213680%7D%7B(1%2Bx)%5E4%7D+%2B+%5Cfrac%7B190280%7D%7B(1%2Bx)%5E5%7D+%3D+0), the solution is actually $0.618938$.

Comment: what is $irr$? a complex number?

Comment: @ Dr. Sonnhard Graubner IRR is a rate.

Comment: Let $x=\frac{1}{1+irr}$. You now have a polynomial of degree $5$ in $x$, which almost certainly cannot be factored nicely. You must use numerical methods.

Comment: @barak manos I am sorry by mistake I wrote false number in the solution.
0.6189 is the solution.

Comment: At least you can tell by Descartes's rule of signs that there is exactly one positive real solution.

Comment: irr = internal rate of return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=irr$. From the formula you have, we let 
$$
f(x)=-156000 + \frac{57080}{(1+x)^1} + \frac{81080}{(1+x)^2} + \frac{176480}{(1+x)^3} + \frac{213680}{(1+x)^4} + \frac{190280}{(1+x)^5}.
$$
So, we see that this comes from initial invest $156000$ and getting back $57080$, $\ldots$, etc on the end of $1st$ through $5th$ years respectively. If the cash flow requires only one time investment and getting enough cash back such as this case, the function $f(x)$ satisfies the following:

1. $f(x)$ is continuous and decreasing for $x\geq 0$.
2. $f(0)>0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) <0$.
3. $f(x)=0$ has a unique positive root.

The reason for 3. is by [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

As for obtaining a numerical value of this unique root, again refer to the Intermediate Value Theorem (IVT). If as you said, $0.6189$ is a root, then we will be able to see that 
$$
f(0.6)>0, \ f(0.7)<0.
$$
Then by the IVT, we have $0.6<x<0.7$. If you want to narrow down this, the next one you try is $f(0.65)$. If this  gives $f(0.65)<0$, then $0.6<x<0.65$. The next one you try is $f(0.625)$, etc.

So, this way of solving for the Internal Rate of Return takes too much time, but it is a good way if the calculator has only basic features such as plugging in numbers and doing arithmetics.

As other comments suggested, Wolfram Alpha or Excel is certainly a better choice if it is available. If you are able to use a Financial Calculator such as BA-IIplus, then there is an option for you to solve for IRR by plugging in the cashflow.