# How to find initial values for calculating IRR manually?

Tags: finance, economics

I want to calculate the [IRR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rate_of_return) manually (as in writing the algorithm) by using the method that is described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_rate_of_return#Numerical_solution). It says I can use the secant method to numerically compute the value.

For the secant method I need to initial values but I'm not yet able to understand how to get them. Wikipedia says:

$$r_1 = \left( A / |C_0| \right) ^{2/(N+1)} - 1$$

$$r_2 = (1 + r_{1})^p - 1$$

where

$$A = \text{ sum of inflows } = C_1 + \cdots + C_N$$

$$p = \frac{\log(\mathrm{A} / |C_0|)}{\log(\mathrm{A} / \mathrm{NPV}_{1,in})}$$

where (according to Wikipedia) $\mathrm{NPV}_{1,in}$ refers to the NPV of the inflows only (that is, $\mathrm{C_0 = 0}$). But it doesn't say how to calculate $\mathrm{NPV}_{1,in}$. I thought I have to use the secant method to calculate NPV, so how can the secant method take as an argument the NPV? Can anyone explain to me how that is meant?

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1937008/2297) provides an example:

$$
0=-156000 + \frac{57080}{(1+x)^1} + \frac{81080}{(1+x)^2} + \frac{176480}{(1+x)^3} + \frac{213680}{(1+x)^4} + \frac{190280}{(1+x)^5}
$$

Here, $C_0=156000$. If I set it to 0, there is no way that I can solve the formula (and I would need the secant method anyway to calculate it):

$$
\mathrm{NPV}_{1,in}=\frac{57080}{(1+x)^1} + \frac{81080}{(1+x)^2} + \frac{176480}{(1+x)^3} + \frac{213680}{(1+x)^4} + \frac{190280}{(1+x)^5}=0
$$

What do I miss? And btw, maybe there is another way to find both initial values? Wikipedia doesn't explain why the above formulas are given and what they mean (and I don't understand the meaning of these formulas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is that NPV$_{1,in}$ is computed based on the initial guess $r_1$, i.e. for your example

$$\mathrm{NPV}_{1,in}=\frac{57080}{(1+r_1)^1} + \frac{81080}{(1+r_1)^2} + \frac{176480}{(1+r_1)^3} + \frac{213680}{(1+r_1)^4} + \frac{190280}{(1+r_1)^5} =  144704 \; ,$$

with

$$r_1 = \left( A / |C_0| \right) ^{2/(N+1)} - 1 = 0.6638757 \; .$$